# How to manipulate AJAX POST data before send using WEBDRIVER ( JAVA )

Tags: java, ajax, selenium, xmlhttprequest, webdriver

I want to manipulate data before sending post data which is the using HTML page JQuery .

There is sending JSon post data below . First loading page after second sending this data .... At this this point I want to manipulate JSon data then sent form .

**posts**
    *`*[["qe:expose", Object { qe="su"}, 1457652370400, 0], ["slipstream:pageview", Object { description="unifiedHome",  event_name="pageview",  platform="web",  more...}, 1457652370456, 0], ["slipstream:action", Object { description="fbLoginFallback",  event_name="action",  extra="{"gk":{"rhp":true},"qe":...0106"},"type":"signup"}",  more...}, 1457652371149, 0]]*`*

Data sending url , method post : www.domain.com/ajax/bz

I want to manipulate some data from there .

It's possible with WEBDRIVER ? I'm using JAVA.

Could you help me about this ? I searched but i didn't found answer. I hope it's possible and you can help me about that.

Thank you all !

Comment: No, you cannot do that. Could you tell us the purpose of posting your data?

Comment: How I can not ? Do you now webdriver selenium ? 

Or how is working Chrome Extensions  ? Ad-Block etc. etc.

Or how is working Chrome ? I think you don't know what I'm asking...

Comment: Could you revise your question so I can understand it, please?

Comment: Thank you for trying to help but you don't have any idea about what I'm asking and selenium webdriver .

Comment: driver = GetBrowser();
  
  if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
   driver.navigate().to(baseUrl);
   Thread.sleep(5000);
   
   js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
   js.executeScript("function showAlert() { alert('success'); }; showAlert()");
   
  } else {
   System.out.println("JS no support");
   
  }

Answer (score 0):

It's possible by injecting a piece of JavaScript.

If what you need just requires to simply force an input then :

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("...");
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("$('...').val('new value');");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("...")).click();  //submit
```

You could also hook the post function :

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("...");
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(
  "var ajax = $.ajax;" +
  "$.ajax = function(url, settings) {" +
  "  alert('post intercepted');" +
  "  ajax.apply(this, arguments);" +
  "};");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("...")).click();  //submit
```